# flask-appbuilder: How to show exception message of post_add() in page

Tags: flask-appbuilder

I have an app based on `flask-appbuilder 3.3.3`. I'd like to do insert some records in `tableB` after adding a record in `tableA`.

I have overridden the `post_add()` method :

```python
class UploadFilesModelView(ModelView):
    datamodel = SQLAInterface(UploadFile)

    def post_add(self, item):
       # do something
       raise exception("error")
```

Although an exception was raised, and it is shown in the console, an error message showed on the web page. It shows the "`list`" page instead.

How to show an exception message of `post_add()` on the page?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible 
you should override your own _add() method 
https://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/flask_appbuilder/baseviews.html#
[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).